# How to abort Axios request in React apps using async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Hi I created a React hook to handle Axios requests. The trouble I'm having is that I'm unable to successfully abort the request to prevent memory leak. When I switch between 2 pages that uses the hook, I get error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
> function.

useAxios hook code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useAxios = (url, method = "GET") => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [body, setBody] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();

    const getData = async (body) => {
      setLoading(true);

      try {
        const res = body
          ? await axios.post(url, body, {
              signal: controller.signal,
            })
          : await axios.get(url, {
              signal: controller.signal,
            });
        setData(res.data);
        setError(null);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (method === "GET") {
      getData();
    } else if (method === "POST") {
      getData(body);
    }

    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [url, method, body]);

  return { data, error, loading, setBody };
};

export default useAxios;
```

Comment: I think that when you make abort - your response ends with AbortError, after you catch it and trying to update state with `setError(err)`, `setLoading(false)`

Answer (score 2):

Your `setError` and `setLoading` are both going to fire when aborting.

So you will want to set a flag in the unmount callback.
You can then conditionally call `setError` / `setLoading` based on this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let aborting = false;
  try {
    ....
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    if (!aborting) {
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
    }
  } 
  ....
  return () => {
    aborting = true;
    controller.abort();
  }
}, ...
```

> prevent memory leak

Just a note, this wound't actually be a memory leak, it's just a warning that it could have come from one.  eg. using `addEventListener` without `removeEventListener`.  But in either case you would still want to prevent a `setState` on a umounted component.

Comment: When you have code that's still running from an unmounted component, that is technically a memory leak. It's something taking up memory that was supposed to be released.